# Whirlpool Cabrio no water at rinse cycle

Tags: appliances

Washer fills fine and runs through wash cycle but when rinse cycle starts no water fills and machine throws LF error and turns off.

Comment: Have you checked their web site and/or called their customer hotline?

Comment: Was there a question in there?

Comment: Yes. Why does water fill for wash cycle but water does not fill when rinse cycle starts and why does machine then throw LF

Comment: Please [edit] your question to put the question in there, not down here in the comments. While you're there, please specify the model #, not just the marketing name. Also, please include any/all troubleshooting steps you've taken so that we don't waste our time and yours by suggesting things you've already done.

Comment: What is this Jeopardy?